# How to avoid breaking lines in React fragments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function which generate a fragment:

```
const f = (first, last) => {
    <>{first}{first.indexOf("\'") > 0 ? "" : " "}<i>{last}</i></>
}
```

Then, I use the function in a piece of HTML

```
<Row>
   here is {f("xxx","yyy")}.
</Row>
```

I expected exactly the following output:

```
<div>
   here is xxx yyy.
</div>
```

but the result in the browser debug is the following:

```
<div> (flex)
"here is "
"xxx"
<i>yyy</i>
"."
</div>
```

and the browser displays as:

```
here is
xxx
yyy (<- this in italic)
.
```

I tried to wrap in a `<span className="nowrap">` with

```
span .nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

with no success.

Can someone provide some help?

Comment: How does it actually render in the browser?

Comment: Could you give us some fiddle? Like this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fragments-forked-l5iy5

Comment: Your css selector is wrong, you need to use `span.nowrap` if you want to match `<span class="nowrap">`

Answer (score 1):

The inspector is just showing you the [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text). You can join up some of these nodes but there's an element node right in between the period and the first part of your text. There's no way around that.

```
{first}{first.indexOf("\'") > 0 ? "" : " "}
```

can be written as:

```
{`${first}${first.indexOf("\'") > 0 ? "" : " "}`}
```

But like I said, the last `.` will be a text node after the `<i>` element.

That being said, the browser (as in the document viewport) should display these text nodes without the line break.